# Halide JIT vs Generator Differences

Tags: halide

While playing around with Halide, I see that totally different pseudocodes are created for a same pipline when using JIT and a generated function approaches. It looks like I'm missing something and so I'd very appreciate and hint. Here is what I did:

A simple 'dilate' pipline is defined as:

```
int jit_main ()
{
    Target target = get_jit_target_from_environment ();
    const int width = 1280, height = 1024;
    Buffer <uint8_t> input (width, height);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            input (x, y) = rand () & 0xff;

    Var x ("x_1"), y ("y_1");

    Func clamped ("clamped_1");
    clamped = BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge (input);

    Func max_x ("max_x_1");
    max_x (x, y) = max (clamped (x - 1, y), clamped (x, y), clamped (x + 1, y));

    Func dilate ("dilate_1");
    dilate (x, y) = max (max_x (x, y - 1), max_x (x, y), max_x (x, y + 1));

    tick (NULL);
    Buffer<uint8_t> out = dilate.realize (width, height, target);
    tick ("inline");

    dilate.print_loop_nest ();
    dilate.compile_to_lowered_stmt ("dilate_1_.html", {}, HTML);
}
```

The resulting pseudocode looks as follows (fragment):

```
    produce dilate_1 {
        let t125 = ((dilate_1.min.1 * dilate_1.stride.1) + dilate_1.min.0)
        for (dilate_1.s0.y_1, dilate_1.min.1, dilate_1.extent.1) {
            let t128 = max(min(dilate_1.s0.y_1, 1024), 1)
            let t126 = max(min(dilate_1.s0.y_1, 1023), 0)
            let t127 = max(min(dilate_1.s0.y_1, 1022), -1)
            let t129 = ((dilate_1.s0.y_1 * dilate_1.stride.1) - t125)
            for (dilate_1.s0.x_1, dilate_1.min.0, dilate_1.extent.0) {
                dilate_1[(dilate_1.s0.x_1 + t129)] = max(b0[((max(min(dilate_1.s0.x_1, 1278), -1) + (t126 * 1280)) + 1)], max(b0[(max(min(dilate_1.s0.x_1, 1279), 0) + (t126 * 1280))], max(b0[((max(min(dilate_1.s0.x_1, 1280), 1) + (t126 * 1280)) + -1)], max(b0[((max(min(dilate_1.s0.x_1, 1280), 1) + (t127 * 1280)) + 1279)], max(b0[((max(min(dilate_1.s0.x_1, 1279), 0) + (t127 * 1280)) + 1280)], max(b0[((max(min(dilate_1.s0.x_1, 1278), -1) + (t127 * 1280)) + 1281)], max(b0[((max(min(dilate_1.s0.x_1, 1280), 1) + (t128 * 1280)) + -1281)], max(b0[((max(min(dilate_1.s0.x_1, 1279), 0) + (t128 * 1280)) + -1280)], b0[((max(min(dilate_1.s0.x_1, 1278), -1) + (t128 * 1280)) + -1279)]))))))))
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I defined a generator:

```
class Dilate0Generator : public Halide::Generator <Dilate0Generator>
{
public:
    Input<Buffer<uint8_t>>  input_0 {"input_0", 2};
    Output<Buffer<uint8_t>> dilate_0 {"dilate_0", 2};
    Var                     x {"x_0"}, y {"y_0"};

    void generate ()
    {
        Func clamped_0 {"clamped_0"};
        clamped_0 = BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge (input_0);

        Func max_x_0 {"max_x_0"};
        max_x_0 (x, y) =
            max (clamped_0 (x - 1, y), clamped_0 (x, y), clamped_0 (x + 1, y));

        dilate_0 (x, y) =
            max (max_x_0 (x, y - 1), max_x_0 (x, y), max_x_0 (x, y + 1));

        dilate_0.print_loop_nest ();
    }
};
HALIDE_REGISTER_GENERATOR (Dilate0Generator, dilate_0)
```

And it's pseudocode is completely different (fragment):

```
    produce dilate_0 {
        let dilate_0.s0.y_0.prologue = min(max((input_0.min.1 + 1), dilate_0.min.1), (dilate_0.extent.1 + dilate_0.min.1))
        let dilate_0.s0.y_0.epilogue$3 = min(max(max((input_0.min.1 + 1), dilate_0.min.1), ((input_0.extent.1 + input_0.min.1) + -1)), (dilate_0.extent.1 + dilate_0.min.1))
        let t166 = (dilate_0.s0.y_0.prologue - dilate_0.min.1)
        let t168 = ((input_0.min.1 * input_0.stride.1) + input_0.min.0)
        let t170 = ((dilate_0.min.1 * dilate_0.stride.1) + dilate_0.min.0)
        let t167 = (input_0.extent.1 + input_0.min.1)
        let t169 = (input_0.extent.0 + input_0.min.0)
        for (dilate_0.s0.y_0, dilate_0.min.1, t166) {
            let t171 = ((max(min((t167 + -1), dilate_0.s0.y_0), input_0.min.1) * input_0.stride.1) - t168)
            let t173 = ((max((min((dilate_0.s0.y_0 + 2), t167) + -1), input_0.min.1) * input_0.stride.1) - t168)
            let t174 = ((max((min(dilate_0.s0.y_0, t167) + -1), input_0.min.1) * input_0.stride.1) - t168)
            let t175 = ((dilate_0.s0.y_0 * dilate_0.stride.1) - t170)
            for (dilate_0.s0.x_0, dilate_0.min.0, dilate_0.extent.0) {
                dilate_0[(dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t175)] = (let t132 = max((min((dilate_0.s0.x_0 + 2), t169) + -1), input_0.min.0) in (let t133 = max(min((t169 + -1), dilate_0.s0.x_0), input_0.min.0) in (let t134 = max((min(dilate_0.s0.x_0, t169) + -1), input_0.min.0) in max(input_0[(t132 + t171)], max(input_0[(t133 + t171)], max(input_0[(t134 + t171)], max(input_0[(t134 + t173)], max(input_0[(t133 + t173)], max(input_0[(t132 + t173)], max(input_0[(t134 + t174)], max(input_0[(t133 + t174)], input_0[(t132 + t174)])))))))))))
            }
        }
        let t183 = (dilate_0.extent.0 + dilate_0.min.0)
        let t184 = (input_0.extent.0 + input_0.min.0)
        let t185 = max((input_0.min.0 + 1), dilate_0.min.0)
        let t178 = min(max((t184 + -1), t185), t183)
        let t177 = min(t183, t185)
        let t176 = (dilate_0.s0.y_0.epilogue$3 - dilate_0.s0.y_0.prologue)
        let t179 = ((input_0.min.1 * input_0.stride.1) + input_0.min.0)
        let t181 = ((dilate_0.min.1 * dilate_0.stride.1) + dilate_0.min.0)
        for (dilate_0.s0.y_0, dilate_0.s0.y_0.prologue, t176) {
            let t189 = (((dilate_0.s0.y_0 + 1) * input_0.stride.1) - t179)
            let t190 = (((dilate_0.s0.y_0 + -1) * input_0.stride.1) - t179)
            let t187 = ((dilate_0.s0.y_0 * input_0.stride.1) - t179)
            let t191 = ((dilate_0.s0.y_0 * dilate_0.stride.1) - t181)
            let t186 = (t177 - dilate_0.min.0)
            for (dilate_0.s0.x_0, dilate_0.min.0, t186) {
                dilate_0[(dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t191)] = (let t140 = max((min((dilate_0.s0.x_0 + 2), t184) + -1), input_0.min.0) in (let t141 = max(min((t184 + -1), dilate_0.s0.x_0), input_0.min.0) in (let t142 = max((min(dilate_0.s0.x_0, t184) + -1), input_0.min.0) in max(input_0[(t140 + t187)], max(input_0[(t141 + t187)], max(input_0[(t142 + t187)], max(input_0[(t142 + t189)], max(input_0[(t141 + t189)], max(input_0[(t140 + t189)], max(input_0[(t142 + t190)], max(input_0[(t141 + t190)], input_0[(t140 + t190)])))))))))))
            }
            let t194 = (((dilate_0.s0.y_0 + 1) * input_0.stride.1) - t179)
            let t195 = (((dilate_0.s0.y_0 + -1) * input_0.stride.1) - t179)
            let t193 = ((dilate_0.s0.y_0 * input_0.stride.1) - t179)
            let t196 = ((dilate_0.s0.y_0 * dilate_0.stride.1) - t181)
            let t192 = (t178 - t177)
            for (dilate_0.s0.x_0, t177, t192) {
                dilate_0[(dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t196)] = max(input_0[((dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t193) + 1)], max(input_0[(dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t193)], max(input_0[((dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t193) + -1)], max(input_0[((dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t194) + -1)], max(input_0[(dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t194)], max(input_0[((dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t194) + 1)], max(input_0[((dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t195) + -1)], max(input_0[(dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t195)], input_0[((dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t195) + 1)]))))))))
            }
            let t200 = (((dilate_0.s0.y_0 + 1) * input_0.stride.1) - t179)
            let t201 = (((dilate_0.s0.y_0 + -1) * input_0.stride.1) - t179)
            let t198 = ((dilate_0.s0.y_0 * input_0.stride.1) - t179)
            let t202 = ((dilate_0.s0.y_0 * dilate_0.stride.1) - t181)
            let t197 = (t183 - t178)
            for (dilate_0.s0.x_0, t178, t197) {
                dilate_0[(dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t202)] = (let t152 = max((min((dilate_0.s0.x_0 + 2), t184) + -1), input_0.min.0) in (let t153 = max(min((t184 + -1), dilate_0.s0.x_0), input_0.min.0) in (let t154 = max((min(dilate_0.s0.x_0, t184) + -1), input_0.min.0) in max(input_0[(t152 + t198)], max(input_0[(t153 + t198)], max(input_0[(t154 + t198)], max(input_0[(t154 + t200)], max(input_0[(t153 + t200)], max(input_0[(t152 + t200)], max(input_0[(t154 + t201)], max(input_0[(t153 + t201)], input_0[(t152 + t201)])))))))))))
            }
        }
        let t203 = ((dilate_0.extent.1 + dilate_0.min.1) - dilate_0.s0.y_0.epilogue$3)
        let t205 = ((input_0.min.1 * input_0.stride.1) + input_0.min.0)
        let t207 = ((dilate_0.min.1 * dilate_0.stride.1) + dilate_0.min.0)
        let t204 = (input_0.extent.1 + input_0.min.1)
        let t206 = (input_0.extent.0 + input_0.min.0)
        for (dilate_0.s0.y_0, dilate_0.s0.y_0.epilogue$3, t203) {
            let t208 = ((max(min((t204 + -1), dilate_0.s0.y_0), input_0.min.1) * input_0.stride.1) - t205)
            let t210 = ((max((min((dilate_0.s0.y_0 + 2), t204) + -1), input_0.min.1) * input_0.stride.1) - t205)
            let t211 = ((max((min(dilate_0.s0.y_0, t204) + -1), input_0.min.1) * input_0.stride.1) - t205)
            let t212 = ((dilate_0.s0.y_0 * dilate_0.stride.1) - t207)
            for (dilate_0.s0.x_0, dilate_0.min.0, dilate_0.extent.0) {
                dilate_0[(dilate_0.s0.x_0 + t212)] = (let t161 = max((min((dilate_0.s0.x_0 + 2), t206) + -1), input_0.min.0) in (let t162 = max(min((t206 + -1), dilate_0.s0.x_0), input_0.min.0) in (let t163 = max((min(dilate_0.s0.x_0, t206) + -1), input_0.min.0) in max(input_0[(t161 + t208)], max(input_0[(t162 + t208)], max(input_0[(t163 + t208)], max(input_0[(t163 + t210)], max(input_0[(t162 + t210)], max(input_0[(t161 + t210)], max(input_0[(t163 + t211)], max(input_0[(t162 + t211)], input_0[(t161 + t211)])))))))))))
            }
        }
    }
```

The generated version runs in an order of magnitude faster, which is not surprising, given that the pseudocode for it looks a lot more optimized.
It runs even faster that [an existed example](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/test/correctness/dilate3x3.cpp)

My noob question is how comes that JIT can not create the same representation?
Thanks a lot for any answer/idea/help/hint...

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that in the JIT case, the size of the input (and thus the location of the boundary condition) is known at compile-time.

However the generated code should be similar. I think the fact that you don't get five separate cases in the JIT case is a bug in Halide. I have opened an issue on the Halide github repo.
https://github.com/halide/Halide/issues/5353

EDIT: Thanks for uncovering a bug! Fixed in https://github.com/halide/Halide/pull/5355

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Bugs of others are always easy :-)